# Cannot install passenger with Nginx

Tags: nginx, ruby, phusion-passenger

I have a rack application that I want to migrate from Ruby 1.8.7 + Apache + passenger to Ruby 1.9.1 + Nginx + passenger.

I have made up the following script for a quick install all in one, and it raises an error...

Here is the installation script: (basic one with all the steps I need to install everything on a Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx fresh box)

**Nginx sources**

```
cd /tmp
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-0.7.66.tar.gz
tar xzf nginx-0.7.66.tar.gz
cd nginx-0.7.66
```

**openssl required for SSL/TLS**

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

**Compilation stuff**

```
sudo apt-get zlib1g-dev
```

**Ruby interpreter 1.9.1**

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev rubygems1.9.1 irb1.9.1 \
ri1.9.1 rdoc1.9.1 build-essential nginx libopenssl-ruby1.9.1
```

**Make sure default ruby uses version 1.9.1**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 400 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz ruby.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.9.1.1.gz --slave /usr/bin/ri ri /usr/bin/ri1.9.1 --slave /usr/bin/irb irb /usr/bin/irb1.9.1 --slave /usr/bin/rdoc rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc1.9.1
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
```

**Passenger (rake-0.8.7, fastthread-1.0.7, rack-1.1.0, passenger-2.2.14)**

```
sudo gem install passenger
```

**Activate Passenger in nginx, select option 2 to use nginx sources donwloaded above**

```
cd /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.14/bin
sudo ./passenger-install-nginx-module
```

And this is the error message I got:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.14/ext/nginx/ContentHandler.c
gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g   -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I /tmp/pcre-8.00 -I objs -I src/http -I src/http/modules -I src/mail \
    -o objs/addon/nginx/StaticContentHandler.o \
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.14/ext/nginx/StaticContentHandler.c
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.14/ext/nginx/StaticContentHandler.c: In function ‘passenger_static_content_handler’:
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.14/ext/nginx/StaticContentHandler.c:71: error: ‘ngx_http_request_t’ has no member named ‘zero_in_uri’
make[1]: *** [objs/addon/nginx/StaticContentHandler.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/nginx-0.7.66'
make: *** [build] Error 2
--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong
Please read our Users guide for troubleshooting tips:
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-2.2.14/doc/Users guide Nginx.html
```

I do not understand the reason of this error. Is this a compatibility problem?
Hope you have any clues :)

Comment: I had a closer look in the code that produces this error and saw there is a check on nginx version. If version is strictly lower than 8038 then "zero_in_uri" is checked. I moved to the last development version 8.0.40 and will make some more tests. Hopefully, the next stable version will not produce this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting the same error with nginx 0.7.67 and Passenger 2.2.14. Looks like this is a bug - a change in nginx triggering a problem in Passenger - based on this ticket, http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=500 and there is a patch in for Passenger 2.2.15.

Comment: As Victor suggests (below) Passenger 2.2.14 installs fine with Nginx 0.7.62.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I'd rather use the latest stable version (for both passenger and nginx). Thanks a lot to both of you guys. Luc